# Move div up when resizing screen

Tags: html, css

I would like to have the top side of a div move up or down when the screen resizes up or down. Currently, if I resize the screen up and I make it shorter, the div gets hidden below the fold.

Basically I would like the div to remain a % of the screen above the fold. I have tried using `top: x%` and `margin-top: x%` instead of absolute numbers like pixels but this doesn't change anything.

Find below snippets of code:

```css
#blogIntro {
  position:absolute;
  background:white;
  width:40%;
  height: 1050px;
  right:300px;
  margin: 20% 20% 150px 40%;
  z-index:1;
  padding:20px;
}

html {
  background: url(Photos/Main_Home.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size:cover;
  -moz-background-size:cover;
  -o-background-size:cover;
  background-size:cover;
  font-size:10px;
  position:relative;
}
```

```html
  <div id="blogIntro">
   <p id="blogIntroTitle"><b>PRY</b>VIT<span class="scrollDown">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;[scroll down]</span></p>
    <h2 id="whoami">WHO AM I</h2>
    <div id="blogIntro1"></div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea viderer conclusionemque pri. Petentium argumentum at vel, pro eu accusam deleniti iudicabit. Te justo malis molestie sit, his an quod mnesarchum. Ludus vulputate cu pri. Nam te consul moderatius scriptorem, vel nostrum vivendum forensibus ex, te persecuti instructior nam.</p>
    </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: seems user tried editing my post and the community rejected it. @Tiddo, I am not an expert coder, I'm just trying to learn. I may not know the coder forum conventions, but seriously, what's wrong in starting my post with a nice little "hello coders of the world" and finishing with a simple "thanks!"? Aren't you overdoing? You have a 2000 something reputation, u probably know the answer to my question, but you didn't even answered.

Comment: Yep, that was me, I understand your argument but see [this meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/3021) for why I did that.

Comment: @joe_young fair enough, thanks 4 sharing. But learners like me would appreciate learning from 2000 something reputation users a bit more than avoid greetings and the like. will try not to greet next time :p

Comment: @perettxintxola - I personally actually agree with you. I think it's a waste of time and effort to edit posts to remove "hi" and "thanks" lines, as well as I think that it's very hostile towards new users. (hence, my edit didn't remove those. The removal of "Hello" and "Thanks" did come up in my review queue, but I actually rejected it. Unfortunately it did get removed by a later edit). Edits are supposed to actually improve stuff, not to remove any form of human interaction. I share your frustration, but unfortunately edits like those just happens a lot on here.

Comment: fair play @Tiddo, thanks for your comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using `vh` unit? It's basically a percentage of the height of the client's window. See [MDN article on viewport percentage lengths](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths).

Also you may be interested in the [calc() CSS function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc).

Comment: @Ashuego vh unit worked, thanks! I also positioned the div as absolute and set body tag to relative, and set top in % and it worked as well.